# VS2010 C# WinForms Pinnable Control

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have done quite a bit of searching on this but haven't been able to find an answer that is workable for me.

I am trying to get a pinned control similar to how the Toolbox works in Visual Studio (unpin and it minimizes to the side of VS, hover over the label and it opens, pin and it stays open after the mouse leaves the area). Does anyone know what this control is called?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/

Comment: I saw that when I was looking around, but I'm not sure it will do what I want it to do. I am working on giving it a try though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Germany we know these kind of controls as "toolwindows".

Comment: I looked at the Tool* controls and doesn't look like they are the right ones...Thanks for the idea though!

Answer (score 0):

You could use The [DockPanel Suite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/) to mimic the behaviour the Toolbox window.

Comment: I tried the DockPanel Suite for the project and had a lot of problems with it. I'm not sure that I will use it again. I'd still be interested in hearing about other docking tools for future reference.

Thanks for the input!